# D3 why d3.histogram array is empty

Tags: d3.js, histogram

Probably this is a simple question, but why when, I am try to assign data to `d3.histogram` generator I have 0 length value array?
The code:

```js
const data = [8,10,16];
const max = 16;
const binCount = data.length;
const width = 100;
const height = 100;

const scaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, binCount])
    .range([0, width]);

const scaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, max])
    .range([0, height]);

const bins = d3.histogram()
    .domain(scaleX.domain())
    (data);
    
console.log(bins);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you look in the actual console log (ctrl + shift + i) and expand the tree branches you can see that it isn't actually empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scale domain for the histogram needs to be `[0, biggest number in your data]`, not `[0, number of items in your data]`

At the moment it's ignoring anything bigger than the value 3 (all of your data points basically)

https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#histogram_domain

*"The histogram domain is defined as an array [min, max], where min is the minimum observable value and max is the maximum observable value; both values are inclusive. Any value outside of this domain will be ignored when the histogram is generated."*

```js
const data = [8,10,16];
const max = 16;
const binCount = data.length;
const width = 100;
const height = 100;

const scaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, width]);

const scaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, max])
    .range([0, height]);

const bins = d3.histogram()
    .domain(scaleX.domain())
    (data);
    
console.log(bins);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```